# Bootstrap 4 transform menu items into a multiselect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Following this example in the Bootstrap documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-dividers

I want the click effects of the menu **items** to be toggled instead, so when I click it it becomes blue, and if I click it again it goes back to unselected. Imitating a multiselect, but I don't want to use checkboxes or the default multiselect.

Can I do this using only css tweaks?

I'm open to any other ideas that implement a more intuitive multiselect, specially for mobile (except external libs)

Comment: Bootstrap's `dropdown-menu` cannot be made to 'toggle' display with pure CSS. Why not simply use a standard multiselect and style it to look like Bootstrap?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I wouldn't know how to do that to be honest, just learning for now

Comment: I doubt you can use pure CSS to do this. Not a problem using JS/JQ though. Let me know if you want the JS solution.

Comment: @LoveHateDevelopment Sure! that's probably the right answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can supply a pure JS solution, but if you're using bootstrap you may as well take advantage of JQ.

**JQuery Solution**

Bootstrap has a class called active already. Obviously just replace .dropdown-item if your classes are named differently.

```
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I have to say it doesn't look as good as I imagined it, but it answers the question